# Run-Time Error 91: Can't run through the second line

Tags: vba, excel

Here is part of the code I am working on which is a part of a macro.

This is also the same on another file which is basically the same also.

The macro works on the other file while on the other, it doesn't and comes with the Run-time error '91'.

Attached is the code:

```
shtData.Activate
Dim r As Integer
Dim strassured As String

r = 1
While ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Select

    strassured = ActiveCell.Value
    If shtWorkSpace.Range("B3").Value = strassured Then
        If shtWorkSpace.Range("A60").Value = "Pending" Then
            DataHandling.OverwriteDataTab (strassured)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "This assured name is already in the database. Assured Names must be unique!", vbCritical
            shtWorkSpace.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Wend
```

Comment: where is `shtWorkSpace` defined and set ?

Comment: Look up Run-time error '91'.  - object variable not set. Which of the objects in your code is not set?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an answer, not to provide how to define and `Set` both worksheets (`shtData` and `shtWorkSpace`).

But also to provide a better coding practice, there is no need to `Activate` worksheets, or use `Select` and `ActiveCell`. Instead use fully qualified `Range`s and `Worksheets`.

**Code**

```
Sub Test()

Dim shtData As Worksheet
Dim shtWorkSpace As Worksheet
Dim r As Integer
Dim strassured As String

Set shtData = Worksheets("Data") '<-- modify "Data" to your sheet name
Set shtWorkSpace = Worksheets("Workspace") '<-- modify "Workspace" to your sheet name

r = 1
While shtData.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    strassured = shtData.Cells(r, 1).Value

    If shtWorkSpace.Range("B3").Value = strassured Then
        If shtWorkSpace.Range("A60").Value = "Pending" Then
            DataHandling.OverwriteDataTab (strassured)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "This assured name is already in the database. Assured Names must be unique!", vbCritical
            shtWorkSpace.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select '<-- not sure why you need to select the sheet and Range("A1")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        r = r + 1
    End If
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for noticing. I've used the Activate worksheet function since the macro kinda looks through several sheets and finds the sheet that is appropriate for the data to be written in a cell or range of cells. So when the macro finds the appropriate sheet, it then activates it and so on.

Comment: @ChristianJasperCabotaje did the code above worked like you needed ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still comes up with the same error.

Comment: @ChristianJasperCabotaje when you run it in debug mode (F8) at what line are you getting the error ?

Comment: At start of the While loop